# RAM vs MongoDB for temporary game data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a game where the current position of each player and game element needs to be handled and remembered by the server.
But once the game is over all I need the server to remember is who won... basically.

So I was wondering if I should store that data inside of an object or inside of the database. I think it would make my code a bit more readable to if I sued the db method and it would also allow me to resume games after a server restart.

But here is the thing: The data is updated hundreds if not thousands of times per second.
Would that significantly increase CPU usage, latency or so?

Comment: I would say a database is completely unsuitable for a real-time gaming application. For an arcade game like Quake the server will retain session data in RAM only.

Comment: I'm with @PaulHK, I would not do DB transactions during the game... But, if you want to allow resuming a game, you could store in DB the state of the game on client disconnect event.

Comment: These two guys above me have a point. Im with them. You dont want to DB calls during game play.